# How to zip/unzip in Zig?

Tags: zip, compression, archive, unzip, zig

How to zip/unzip a file from Zig? Do I need to do it using C library or there is a *native* way?

For now I searched a bit but didn’t find any actual info. Only [issue](https://github.com/ziglang/zig/issues/213) about implementing Deflate algorithm. But I don’t know if it really what a searching for…

Answer (score 1):

According to that issue (https://github.com/ziglang/zig/issues/213) "deflate" (and a couple other (de)compression algorithms) are provided in the Zig standard library (see the v0.11.0 [`std.compress` "doc"](https://ziglang.org/documentation/0.11.0/std/#A;std:compress)).   Additionally, "deflate" seems to be the standard ZIP compression algorithm: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10214598/960524.

That said, there doesn't seem to (yet) be any handling of ZIP *archives* in Zig.
A zip archive or file is a collection of separately compressed entries.

So in the short-term, you can probably leverage an existing C library, or spawn an unzip subprocess.